# Customized excel download from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote code for download excel file from mysql database in PHP. But where as I want to download the customized excel file from database. Like, in my database there is name,inst1date,inst2date,inst3date.... I want that in my excel there will be name and date field where date will be between two dates which I will input. It picks names and respective inst1date or inst2date or inst3date.... where it match.

```
    <?php
    // include "config_1.php";
    // ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    include('db_con.php');


     $todo=$_POST['todo'];
    $search_text=$_POST['search_text'];
    $todo2=$_POST['todo2'];
    $search_text2=$_POST['search_text2'];

     $query="select * from installment where inst1date between '$search_text' and '$search_text2' or inst2date between '$search_text' and '$search_text2' or inst3date between '$search_text' and '$search_text2'";
    $stmt=$db_con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();


    $columnHeader ='';
    $columnHeader = "Sr NO"."\t"."Roll"."\t"."Name"."\t"."Parent Name"."\t"."Course Name"."\t"."Course Fees"."\t"."Batch"."\t"."Due Amount"."\t"."Admission Date"."\t"."Admission Amount"."\t"."Admission Status"."\t"."Installment 1 Date"."\t"."Installment 1 Amount"."\t"."Installment 1 Status"."\t"."Installment 2 Date"."\t"."Installment 2 Amount"."\t"."Installment 2 Status"."\t"."Installment 3 Date"."\t"."Installment 3 Amount"."\t"."Installment 3 Status"."\t"."Installment 4 Date"."\t"."Installment 4 Amount"."\t"."Installment 4 Status"."\t"."Installment 5 Date"."\t"."Installment 5 Amount"."\t"."Installment 5 Status"."\t"."Installment 6 Date"."\t"."Installment 6 Amount"."\t"."Installment 6 Status"."\t"."Installment 7 Date"."\t"."Installment 7 Amount"."\t"."Installment 7 Status"."\t"."Installment 8 Date"."\t"."Installment 8 Amount"."\t"."Installment 8 Status";


    $setData='';

    while($rec =$stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $rowData = '';
      foreach($rec as $value)
      {
        $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        $rowData .= $value;
      }
      $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";
    }


    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=duelist.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    echo ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";

    ?>

    Database table :
    ----------------

______________________________________________________________
    Name     |  inst1date    |  inst2date   |   inst3date
_____________|_______________|______________|_________________
    Arjun    |  2019-03-02   |  2019-04-03  |   2019-05-04
_____________|_______________|______________|_________________   
    Sachin   |  2019-04-05   |  2019-05-06  |   2019-06-07


    Input Date 2019-04-02 To 2019-04-09
    -----------------------------------

    Expected Output Excel Structure
    -------------------------------


   Name     |      Date
____________|_______________            
    Arjun   |     2019-04-03
____________|________________
    Sachin  |     2019-04-05
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your SQL

```
$query= '
  SELECT
    name, DATE_FORMAT(inst1date, "%M %d %Y") AS inst1date ...
  FROM installment
  WHERE inst1date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
  LIMIT 100
';
```

1. You MUST escape your variables or be at risk of SQL injection. i suggest using php PDO or mysqli.
2. avoid using `*` as it will get everything from the table which may not be all needed. Instead use field1, field2

   3. [DATE_FORMAT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) can format SQL in a lot of different formats
   4. Instead of using mysql to format the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can use php `$d = date("format", time);`

--Update

SELECT
      *
    FROM installment
    WHERE 
        ( 
            inst1date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
        ) OR
        ( 
            inst2date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
        ) OR
        ( 
            inst3date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
        ) 
    LIMIT 100

Will return rows where any of the inst1date, inst2date or inst3date is between search terms. You need to process the results in PHP as your table is kinda of poorly designed for this type of query.

```
while($rec =$stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $rowData = '';
      foreach($rec as $key => $value)
      {

        if( 
            ( $key == 0 ) || // Will pass for the name param as it is the first in your row
            ( 
                $rec["inst1date"]) >= strtotime($search_text) && strtotime($rec["inst1date"]) <= strtotime($search_text)    
            )|| 
            // Repeat for inst2date and inst3date
        ){
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            $rowData .= $value;
        }
      }
      $setData .= trim($rowData)."\n";

}
```

// This is a php solution. It is messy because the SQL table is kind of messy

Changing the sql query will yield a much better results

```
SELECT
  name, 
#You could also add a format function too
  CASE 
    WHEN inst1date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'` THEN inst1date
    WHEN inst2date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'` THEN inst2date
    ELSE inst3date
  END AS date
FROM installment
WHERE 
    ( 
        inst1date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
    ) OR
    ( 
        inst2date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
    ) OR
    ( 
        inst3date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
    ) 
LIMIT 100
```

The query above will return only two fields(a name field and a date field)

-- Second update

I think if you refactor your table like so it would be 100% easier to query. Example:

```
id      |   name     |      date
________|____________|_______________            
1       |    Arjun   |     2019-04-03 23:00:01
________|____________|________________
2       |    Sachin  |     2019-04-05 22:00:01
________|____________|________________
3       |    Sachin  |     2019-06-05 21:00:01
```

Just keep inserting into the table for every instdate you want to track. Using a user_id and joins would be even better(replace name with user_id from the users table)

```
$query= '
  SELECT
    CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", u.last_name) AS name,
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date
  FROM installment AS i
  JOIN users AS u ON u.id = i.user_id 
  WHERE date BETWEEN `'.$search_text.'` and `'.$search_text2.'`
  #OPTIONALLY ADD GROUP BY TO LIMIT RESULTS
  LIMIT 100
';
```

Using the above would use the relational nature of the DB. Refactoring the trable vertically instead of horizontally would allow you to do inst1date, inst2date,inst3date, inst4date and so on. With each entry you are effectively adding another date field. Odiviously, you can see this is a better oranizational technique. As well, you can create more indepth queries as you can contain more data without having to continually add fields.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my code. Now you can understand what I want as output

Comment: Look at my suggestions either use php to format the date `date("Y-m-d", field)` or use mysql to format your date field `DATE_FORMAT(inst1date, %Y-%m-%d")` also what is in the table? * is going to get everything it looks like you only want two fields (name, date) -> adjust your SQL

Comment: I want to pick up the names and dates where it matches. After pick up the dates I want to put it in a excel file. I can not customize my excel file,

Comment: what fields are in your table?  using * will select all fields. Be specific

Comment: Please look down to my code, then you will understand what I'm trying to.

Comment: @DebayanMondal i adjusted my answer. I think what you are trying to do is return an individual if insta1-3 is between two dates. If you want to return how many occurrences you will need to either add a group by or change the query entirely. The setup for the database table would likely work better using joins ( one of the most important concepts within a relational database)

Comment: 1st while loop shows error near "             )||  "... It shows syntax error.

Comment: @DebayanMondal correct. The code is not complete `||` means `OR`. You would just copy the code for the other two fields ` $rec["inst2date"]) >= strtotime($search_text) && strtotime($rec["inst12date"]) <= strtotime($search_text)` as i said this approach is messy and will yeild funny results because the condition can be statisfied if any of the dates match the period

Comment: It can't help me out. Please refresh the answer with expected output

Comment: i think you may find it easier to create table models and use an ORM - this would eliminate your need to create sql queries but its a new toy to figure out. Read my above answer - i updated it several times to address your concerns as well as the query. i gave you two different approaches (SQL vs PHP). I think the SQL approach is better as it yeild correct data where PHP you need to filter the data.